# MongoDB Using Mongoose Filter Based on SubDocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a one to many relationship between Dish and Review. One dish can have many reviews. Here is the Mongoose Schema for Dish and Review:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Review = require('./reviewSchema')

// defining the structore of your document
let dishSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name : String,
  price :Number,
  imageURL :String,
  reviews : [Review.schema]
})

// convert the schema into a model class which you can use in your code
const Dish = mongoose.model('Dish',dishSchema)

module.exports = Dish


const mongoose = require('mongoose')

let reviewSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title : String,
  description :String
})

const Review = mongoose.model('Review',reviewSchema)

module.exports = Review
```

The problem I am having is that I want to fetch all the dishes if they have at least one review. Here is the code I wrote which returns an empty array.

```
Dish.find({
  "reviews.length" : { $gt : 0 }
},function(error,dishes){
  console.log(dishes)
})
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't explicitly refer to `length` property of an array. To check if array is not empty you can check if it's of [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) `"array"` and if its [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/index.html) is [$not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/index.html) `0`.

```
Dish.find({ reviews: { $type: "array", $not: { $size: 0 } } },
    function(error,dishes){
      console.log(dishes)
})
```